# 64 bit c++ console application in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Using Visual Studio 2015 Community, I want to create a console application in C++. If I use file-->new-->project, and try to find a suitable template, I can find console application under win32. Does "win32" imply it will be for a 32 bit machine (runnable on a 64 bit machine, ub not optimum)? Is there some other route I should be taking if I'm only interested in 64 bit machines?

Comment: A 64-bit OS does not mean you should use 64-bit executables. 64-bit exes are considerably slower in most cases than 32-bit running on the same hardware. You only need to target 64-bit if you need to allocate extremely large amounts of memory (> 2GB) or have a very specific need to use 64-bit registers and operations.

Comment: Thanks. I won't need too much memory, but I'm interested in doing arithmetic on 64 bit integers.

Comment: You can do math on 64-bit integers without creating a 64-bit application. 32-bit applications support 64-bit integers and have for decades now.